# how to use the method each_with_index in ruby, I wanna change the index of a given array

Tags: ruby

I wanna change the index of a given array:

```
arr = ["cat", "tiger", "lion"]
```

so lion-item will have the value of 5-index, tiger will have value of 4-index and 3 for cat-item

is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: how should the outcome look like? `[nil,nil,nil,"cat", "tiger", "lion"]`?

Comment: @UriAgassi the same order but with using another order index, starting from 3 if u know wot I mean?

Comment: Apparently sawa knows wot you mean ;-)

Comment: I don't think it is unclear, he want to access the elements based on another index so he doesn't have to convert the index every time. For example: `arr[3] #=> 'cat'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with a `Hash`:

```
hash = {
  3 => "cat",
  4 => "tiger",
  5 => "lion"
}

hash[4]
#=> "tiger"
```

If you want to convert from an Array to a Hash you can do this:

```
arr = ["cat", "tiger", "lion"]
hash = Hash[arr.each_with_index.map{|v,i| [i+3, v] }]
#=> {"cat"=>3, "tiger"=>4, "lion"=>5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with `each_with_index`, but you can do it with `with_index`.

```
arr.each.with_index(3) do |e, i|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes.it is.. But OP's output is not clear . :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible you can create a index method to acces it.

```
def get_by_index(array, value)
  array[value-3]
end
```

You can also create a new array child class who inherits from array and redefine an square bracket method as explained here:

[How does defining [square bracket] method in Ruby work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018900/how-does-defining-square-bracket-method-in-ruby-work)