# How define custom method of class with special character like [] array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods

how can I create `_[ args ]()` method in one class?

like said here [How does defining [square bracket] method in Ruby work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018900/how-does-defining-square-bracket-method-in-ruby-work)

```
a[b] is the same as a.[](b)
a[b] = c is the same as a.[]=(b, c)
```

I want to do the same thing but with my special characters, like :

```
my_instance_['foo'] have to be same as my_instance._[]('foo')
my_instance_[:bar] = :baz  have to be same as my_instance._[]=(:bar, :baz)
```

"_[]" special named method with no "()" needed, and no "." point too, when call it.

**How writte declaration of this method in ruby?**

thx.

Comment: `[['foo']]` is just passing `['foo']` to the `[]` method.

Comment: @August ok, change special character so : [[]] became _[] for exemple. I have EDIT my question.

Comment: defining a method named `_[]` is not possible. It would be ambiguous in any case.

Comment: If you're trying to define a new operator called `_[]`, that is impossible. You cannot define new operators in Ruby (or the vast majority of other languages).

Comment: @Matrix for what reason you want to do something very weird? maybe you want to learn some Perl magic?

Comment: @gaussblurinc I want use magic access to my method, to implement my own array system.

Comment: @Matrix You can't do that, it's impossible, as I stated.

Comment: @Matrix, maybe you want implement [Iterator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)? It is really better to understand this pattern rather than try to invent new syntax sugar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want instances of your class to be able to use `[]`, then you define a method on the class called `[]`:

```
class Test
  def [](index)
    puts index
  end
end

Test.new['3'] # writes '3'
```

In your example, you would use

```
my_instance_ = Test.new
my_instance_[3]
```

Comment: @Matrix What you want to do is *impossible*. You cannot use `_[]`, it cannot work. Writing `my_instance_[]` will **always** be parsed as accessing a method or local variable called `my_instance_` and invoking `[]` on the return value.

Comment: ... You want `_||` to be a method? Or you want to be able to index things using `my_instance|3|`? Neither option can work. Again, you **cannot invent operators**. That would involve introducing changes to the way that Ruby is parsed. You **can't do that**. You can only change the behaviors of existing operators. If you want an "indexed" operator, your *only* options are `[]` and `()`.

Comment: `my_instance|3|` yes. In fact, I don't understand why [] exception works and why we can't add more exceptions. It will be interesting to let control to make own "magic method".

Comment: Because matz says so.

Comment: @Matrix Because that's the grammar of the language. Ruby makes specific allowances for you to define your own `[]` and `()` behaviors, and **no others**. It doesn't allow you to define your own operators, it allows you to *change* existing operators so they have meaning for your classes. There is no "magic method", so stop looking for one.