# What’s does the [5.0] in Rails 5’s ActiveRecord::Migration mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

A migration I created in a Rails 5 application had `5.0` passed into a method:

```
class CreateVariableKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  ...
end
```

I would like to know what the `[5.0]` means.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a class method of `ActiveRecord::Migration` and is defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0e835960c78f81bf0a78463d4bee2915a9b75de3/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L526).

It allows us to select the version of migrations we wish to use between `4.2` and `5.0`. The method throws a:

> "Unknown migration version ... "

error if an incompatible version is passed as an argument.

Production ready versions of `ActiveRecord` don’t have that method so it should go away as soon as *Rails 5* goes out of beta.

Comment: [Rails 5.0](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/) was released 30th June 2016. Creating a migration still displays the version ```class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]```. Running ```bundle show activerecord``` returns ```/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0```

Answer (score 7):

[This blog has more info too](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/01/migrations-are-versioned-in-rails-5.html)

It seems to be there so that you don't have to upgrade old migrations, when moving from rails 4 to rails 5. (There are some small changes in the migrations API).

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you can define a method named `[]` on a class like so:

```
class Foo
  def self.[](arg)
    puts arg
  end
end
```

And call it like this:

```
Foo["print me"]
--> "print me"

Foo[2.3]
--> 2.3
```

[See this answer for an explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018900/how-does-defining-square-bracket-method-in-ruby-work)

In Rails 7.0, `ActiveRecord::Migration[version_number]` contains this code ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d60d0587c3c10c891b717299ed052ded5658c20d/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L568)):

```
def self.[](version)
  Compatibility.find(version)
end
```

Where `Compatibility::find` ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d60d0587c3c10c891b717299ed052ded5658c20d/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb#L6)) finds the appropriate version of the migration, which you can verify using `rails c`:

```
irb(main):001:0> ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
=> ActiveRecord::Migration::Compatibility::V5_2
```

Hope that helps.