# What are the brackets [5.1] after ActiveRecord Migration and how does it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

When generating a new migration using `bin/rails g migration CreateUser` the first line will look like this:

```
class CreateUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

What does the `[5.1]` stand for and how does it work?

This is a follow up on [What’s does the [5.0] in Rails 5’s ActiveRecord::Migration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302197/what-s-does-the-5-0-in-rails-5-s-activerecordmigration-mean) as it does not explain how this is legal ruby and does not show up in search using `[5.1]` or `brackets`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the new migration versioning introduced with Rails 5. The number indicates the migration version the migration was created with, in this case version `5.1` and should be used with Rails versions `>= 5.0`.

This is a class function `def self.[](version)` of the `ActiveRecord::Migration`, which calls `Compatibility.find(version)` and is used for backward compatibility.

Here are the code references from GitHub:

- [ActiveRecord::Migration::[]](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96aa18974adf7321f265eafbdfe74c7c6e007cb0/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L532)
- [ActiveRecord::Migration::Compatibility](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96aa18974adf7321f265eafbdfe74c7c6e007cb0/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb)